# Need help in Xpath in ftl

Tags: xpath, freemarker

I am trying to give a xpath in ftl that is similar to "abc/xyz[2]".

my ftl code:

```
<#assign X = (Document["abc/xyz"][0])!>
```

Here comes the problem.. I need to write another assign statement using X to achieve "abc/xyz[2]". Something similar to :  **<#assign Y = X[[2]]>** (**Note**: This doesn't work)
Can you please help me out with this statement.

What i already know:
I know that the below statements work

```
<#assign X = (Document["abc"][0])!>
<#assign Y = X["xyz"[2]]>
```

Comment: `<#assign Y = X["xyz"[2]]>` just means `<#assign Y = X["z"]>`. While it doesn't give an error, it does something different than what you mean. But see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
<#assign Y = X.xyz[2]>
```

which is the same as `<#assign Y = X["xyz"][2]>`, just more concise.

Comment: yes, I do ... can you please help me with 
 <#assign Y = X[[2]]> (Note: This doesn't work)

Comment: <#assign Y = X.xyz[2]> works... But that isn't my question. Let me explain it again ... I am looking for something similar to 
<#assign Y = X.[2]>. Please read the 1st half of my question again

Answer (score 0):

You say you want `abc/xyz[2]`, that is, the 2nd `xyz` of each `abc`. You can't get it from `X`, as you have a `[0]` there, so it only contains the first `abc`. So you need `<#assign abcs = Document.abc>`, and then you could do `<#assign X = abcs[0]!>` and `<#assign Y = abcs["xyz[2]"]>`.